# ModelAttribute causing 400 Error Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/editProduct/{productId}")
public String editProduct(@PathVariable("productId") String productId,Model model){

    Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
    model.addAttribute(product);
    return "editProduct";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/admin/productInventory/editProduct",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,HttpServletRequest request){



    MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    Path path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

    if(productImage !=null && !productImage.isEmpty()){
        try{
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("product image failed",e);
        }
    }


    productDao.editProduct(product);
    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";

}
```

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Category">Category</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                         value="Instrument"/>Instrument</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                         value="Record"/>Record</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category"
                                                         value="accessory"/>Accessory</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <form:input path="productDescription" id="description" class="form-control" value="${product.productDescription}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">price</label>
        <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-control" value="${product.productName}"/>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="condition">Condition</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition"
                                                         value="New"/>New</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition"
                                                         value="Used"/>Used</label>
    </div>
```

Upload Picture

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status"
                                                         value="active"/>Active</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status"
                                                         value="inactive"/>inActive</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="unitInStock">Unit in stock</label>
        <form:input path="unitInStock" id="unitInStock" class="form-control" value="${product.unitInStock}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="manufacturer">manufacturer</label>
        <form:input path="productManufacturer" id="manufacturer" class="form-control" value="${product.productManufacturer}"/>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory"/>" class="button btn-default">Cancel</a>

    </form:form>
```

public class Product {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String productId;
private String productName;
private String productCategory;
private String productDescription;
private double productPrice;
private String productCondition;
private String productStatus;
private int unitInStock;
private  String productManufacturer;

@Transient
private MultipartFile productImage;

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductCategory() {
    return productCategory;
}

public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
    this.productCategory = productCategory;
}

public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

public double getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getProductCondition() {
    return productCondition;
}

public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
    this.productCondition = productCondition;
}

public String getProductStatus() {
    return productStatus;
}

public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
    this.productStatus = productStatus;
}

public int getUnitInStock() {
    return unitInStock;
}

public void setUnitInStock(int unitInStock) {
    this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
}

public String getProductManufacturer() {
    return productManufacturer;
}

public void setProductManufacturer(String productManufacturer) {
    this.productManufacturer = productManufacturer;
}

public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
    return productImage;
}

public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
    this.productImage = productImage;
}
```

}

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.emusicstore</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000024" />
</bean>
```

I'm getting a 400 error i dont what im doing wrong but for example if i remove the ModelAttribute then it works can someone help me out whats going wrong here. If i create new controller for example then the post works but without its not i tried to check with firefox debugger i see a bad request.

Comment: could you please add the begin of form declaration ?

Comment: Also a little introduction wouldn't hurt - what server are you using?  What container, what version of Java, etc.

Comment: <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/editProduct" method="post"
                   modelAttribute="product" enctype="multipart/form-data"> im using Tomcat 8.0 server and jdk 1.8.0

Comment: can you post the `Product` class?

Comment: can you share the spring configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bad practice to use entities as the model in the `MVC` layer, try to use separate models.

You have a typo here Product Price is a `double` it can't be assigned to a String .

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">price</label>
        <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-control" value="${product.productName}"/>
  </div>
```

Change it to :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">price</label>
            <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-control" value="${product.productPrice}"/>
      </div>
```

And avoid using `primitives` as model attributes, other wise  you will end up with useless default values in the view and an error if you submit their input empty because `primitives` don't have a default `null` value.

Comment: Thanks this worked me i dont know how i didnt see that.